# Get model from partial view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to pass model to controller with `@Html.Partial`?

Using plain `<td>` in view return list of rows, while this exact same `<td>` wrapped in partial returns `null` on form submit

```
   @using ( Html.BeginForm() )
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    @for ( int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++ )
                    {
                        @*<td class="row">Book @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.Rows[i].RowNum) @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Rows[i].Selected, Model.Rows[i].Data)  </td>*@
                        @Html.Partial("Row", Model.Rows[i])
                    }
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Html.Partial renders a partial view.
If your view is already expecting a model of that type, you can pass it along.

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName", Model)
```

To send values to an action of a controller, you can try using `Html.Action`

```
@Html.Action("actionName","ControllerName", new {RowNum = Model.Row[i].RowNum})
```

You can pass values using the anonymous object

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [RenderPartial Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), it should give you what you need.

Comment: The difference between the Html.Partial he is using and the Html.RenderPartial as the latter is written to the response stream directly while the former is returned as a string.

Comment: @scartag, you are correct, I just wasn't able to find the link to the Partial extension that would benefit submitter. You're answer would also meet their needs and would not require treating the razor syntax as a C# line of code. Thanks for the feedback